# Built part of LEGO set - reds and greys and blacks and a computer screen

Tags: set-identification

Any ideas on what this is part of please? Thanks for your help as always.

[image: reds and greys and blacks and a computer screen]

Comment: FWIW it looks like you have parts from more than one set, judging by the two answers currently available. That 2x2 computer screen is shown as only existing in only one set, but that set doesn't have some of the other parts you've shown.

Comment: Thanks stackex community. That has solved my problems - we have the plane and parts of the tower from the superhero airport battle. Also, have all the star wars minifigs! It's very much appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 12):

After having a good look at [sets with 2x2 dark red curved slopes](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=15068&v=1&in=A&colorID=59&srt=0&srtAsc=A&ov=Y), I'm certain that you have parts from Star Wars Battlefront set [75134-1 Galactic Empire Battle Pack](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75134-1), specificaly parts of the... I guess we could call this a "gun platform"?:

[image: Detail of set 75134-1]

Note the top-right of the image: bley 1x2 printed tile, dark red 2x2 curved slopes, dark bley hinges.

(As @RSchulz has already pointed out, the 2x2 tile with clip and sticker comes from a different set.)

Comment: "Bley"? As a non-hardcore Lego person, is this a term other people would be familiar with? It shows up in Urban Dictionary, but nowhere else.

Comment: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/238/what-is-the-bley-blay-color :-D

Answer (score 9):

Part [Road Sign 2 x 2 Square with Open O Clip with Computer Screen with White, Red and Black Lines Pattern (Sticker)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15210pb014) only appears in set [76051](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76051-1) **Super Hero Airport Battle**.

But that set doesn't seem to have the red curved slope or the 1x2 printed tile from the first few images, so I'm guessing there's more than one set involved.

[image: 76051]

Comment: Good call on the 2x2 computer screen, since it's not present in the set in Ivan's answer!

Comment: I assume only because I got there first. I didn't realize the curved slopes were Dark Red, which would have saved me a **lot** of futile searching.

Comment: AFAIK Star Wars sets tend to use Dark Red so that's why I looked at those. And yes, I too become annoyed by Red vs Dark Red vs Reddish Brown vs Dark Brown.