# Different shades of the same color

Tags: colour

I’ve bought a 10232 set recently online (not official store, some Amazon seller). The box and all packs were properly sealed, but I see some bricks have the same color (grey), but different shades. I even see two similar bricks of the same color but different shades. Has the seller tricked me?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The white balance in your photos seems a bit out, and it's difficult to judge the colours. You might be dealing with a case of pre-2004 grey pieces mixed with post-2004 bley pieces (read https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/238/what-is-the-bley-blay-color ). Perhaps a macro photograph of the underside of the tiles might help further?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It’s already night over here, I am sorry for the picture quality. Will come back tomorrow with a proper pictures.

Comment: @IvanSanchez that's hardly possible. 10232 set has been released in 2013 - whole 9 years after switching to LBG.

Comment: I would not dare to read @IvanSanchez's mind, but I assumed he was suggesting the Amazon seller had sold a "sealed" bag which was not sealed by Lego itself, but perhaps sealed after collecting the pieces from elsewhere. Perhaps someone has war stories of how late Lego themselves were caught shipping a mix of greys in (in particular Star Wars) sets.

Comment: @RSchulz Indeed: from the way OP wrote the question, it's not 100% clear whether the sealed box and all packs are the original box and bags from a factory, or re-sealed by the amazon seller. I haven't personally heard of mixed greys in the same boxed set.

Answer (score 3):

[10232](https://brickset.com/sets/10232-1) was released long after the switch from old grey to new grey, so that's a bit unlikely.

The photos are not very good for seeing color differences on, but I see nothing of notice. I've seen far bigger variations within what LEGO deems acceptable. Fans generally have higher standards for colour matching than LEGO, I knew a fellow fan who had sorted his yellow bricks in 6 different shades.

Comment: And the reason behind this is a switch from using pre-colored plastic pellets to mixing colors locally. Thus slight inconsistency in shades of color. Until this day TLG hasn't managed to resolve this issue, which is a shame.

Comment: I've heard our local certified Lego professional say he has discussed this with Lego and the response what that the target market (kids) doesn't notice nor care about the difference...

Comment: LEGO seems to be trying to appreciate and focus on AFOL's more.  Maybe now is the right time for this issue to get traction within the company.

Comment: My feeling is the opposite. 5-10 years ago LEGO listened and did a lot more to/for AFOL's

Comment: i have added one more photo in the end of the question. this is a blue shades... Sent this set back to amazon seller, if it's an original Lego manufacturer, then shame on Lego company...