# Looking for piece name with 3 small bars, adjoined to each other, and 2 larger circles on the side

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

I am looking for the name of a piece. I haven't seen this piece before, but it's a perfect match for micro scale Dutch bridges. It's a piece with 3 small bars, adjoined to each other. The bottom bar has 2 larger circles on the side. I think its size is about 1x3.

I have added 2 pictures of it:

[image: 3 small bars, adjoined to each other, and 2 larger circles on the side]
[image: 3 small bars, adjoined to each other, and 2 larger circles on the side]

Comment: Just went through the Bars, Minifig Utensils, Window Glass and Shutter, Fence, and Door categories on BrickLink and couldn't find a match. Do you have a link for where you found the images?

Comment: I had better luck looking through the "miscellaneous" section of the LDraw parts database :-)

Comment: Apparently it does not exist in white! The pictures are probably renders, not actual builds. @IvanSanchez found the part, apparently it's an oldskool part that's only available in light grey

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's part [969 Trailer Stand](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=969).

Apparently it appeared only in (old) light grey in sets from the early 70s, and not in white as your picture suggests.

[image: CAD rendering of part]

[image: Truck with part highlighted]

Comment: Great find! The pictures must be renders then, too bad. But I can see they are still for sale, so maybe I'll just make the bridge grey then!

Comment: Yeah, grey should be just fine for the counterweights of bascule bridges :-) Be aware that old (pre-2000) grey is not the same as modern [bley](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/238/what-is-the-bley-blay-color), anyway.

Comment: I'm not convinced the part is white in the op's pictures. All those light parts might very well be grey (possibly a mix of old grey and new bluish grey) - [white balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_balance) can do that to a picture.

Comment: I doubt that, since [3024pb010 1x1 plate with black square pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3024pb010) only exists in white.

Comment: OP's picture is 3D render, not a photo. 3D models could use non-existing colors.  @IvanSanchez it won't stop you from using whichever color you want for that piece while creating 3D model.